# Combining IF AND OR statements for student Bonus marks

Tags: microsoft-excel

To determine which student gets a "bonus" mark of 5, a GRAD student must be PRESENT in both SEMINARS.

An undergrad student, UGRAD, must have been present in either SEM 1 or SEM 2.

If a grad student had attended on one or no seminars, bonus=0. If an ugrad student attended none, bonus=0.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfcPX.png]

I came up with formulas for both undergrad, ugrad and for grad students but am having difficulty combing the functions into one as required.

for GRAD I used:

```
=IF(AND(Status="grad",Sem_1="present",Sem_2="present"),5,0)
```

for UGRAD I used:

```
=IF(OR(Sem_1="present",Sem_2="present"),5,0)
```

** EDIT only one formula may be used

Comment: Homework assumes you've learned the lessons yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework help request where OP has not begun resolving the question themselves.

Comment: Do you mean that the formulas are working, but you want one that combines them and works for both? 
In that case, just make another `IF` that checks the status for either grad or ugrad and then run one code if true and the other if false.

Comment: I don't feel that fair as I've tried several formulas, rearranging them after watching videos and excel tutorials and nothing seems to make sense to me, I showed the steps by presenting two seperate formulas I used for the two seperate statuses and one of my attempts of merging the two formulas together, one of many, however to the same result. If you feel that was that is reasonable but I really hope others don't.

Comment: Use two different cells and hide the computation cells then just A1 AND B1

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Thank you I'll try doing that

Comment: Listing some of the methods you've tried and instructions you've read and how they didn't work would have shown you'd done more than create two IF statements.

Comment: @music2myear I included a formula which I felt made sense and should work in the picture in the OP. I had others like it that essentially gave the same result seen in the yellow column, so felt it would be redundant. I am not here to be given an answer, instead other ways for a person inexperienced in excel to approach the problem. Thanks to one of the replies I am attempting something along the lines of https://exceljet.net/formula/nested-if-function-example and using multiple if statements.

Comment: -1  you should have come up with simple examples to test your understanding of IF and AND and to see where you are getting stuck.. That's basic troubleshooting And furthermore if you'd done that and then get stuck, then it'd no longer be a homework question and wouldn't get closed.

Answer (score 2):

With If you can use:
`=IF(AND(Status="grad",Sem_1="present",Sem_2="present"),5,IF(AND(Status="ugrad",OR(Sem_1="present",Sem_2="present")),5,0))`

I have combined your 2 ifs in one by adding and status, it is a nested if in the false part you can start a second statement.
I tried it with normal references:
`=IF(AND(B3="grad",C3="present",D3="present"),5,IF(AND(B3="ugrad",OR(C3="present",D3="present")),5,0))`
with the same display of your picture
column B is status
column C and D Sem_1 and Sem_2

Answer (score -1):

With no `IF` statements, just for fun. In cell `H5`:

```
=5*(0<(Status="grad")*((Sem_1="present")*(Sem_2="present"))+(Status="ugrad")*((Sem_1="present")+(Sem_2="present")))
```

[image]

I would further improve this worksheet by changing any status that is `present` to `1` and `absent` to `0`. You can use custom number formats to make them appear as "present" and "absent" (namely, by selecting those cells, hitting Ctrl+1, going to Custom, and specifying `"present";;"absent"` as the format.

[image]

This will make the table look exactly the same but the formula gets much shorter:

```
=5*(0<(Status="grad")*(Sem_1+Sem_2)+(Status="ugrad")*(Sem_1*Sem_2))
```

[image]

This is also easier to maintain -- if you ever want to change, say, from "present/absent" to "attended/missed" you won't have to edit the formula. In other words, the formula doesn't make assumptions about the wording of the Sem_1 and Sem_2 cells, only their values. It also makes easier to count how many students were present/absent, for example.

Comment: Use `Evaluate Formula` to check how the formula works. `Alt`, `M`, `V` will pop up the evaluate formula dialog, and you can it `Alt`+`E` to go through each step.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for going into all that effort to help with the question, I truly appreciate it. In regards to the OP, the column "J" contains the results I would want, the formula you provided wasn't able to achieve that. I was happy to learn about ability to see how formulas work step by step and I'm sure that will be useful to me in later work. I feel in this scenario IF statements are most probably needed.

Comment: IF statements are not needed. I misread the question and missed the column J. Basically you just have to flip the + and * between Sem_1 and Sem_2. I'll update the answer right away.

Comment: The wonders of excel I imagine. Always more than one way to go about a scenario, thanks for the help Andre!! The evaluate tool definitely helps understand how things work, I'll try to come up the an IF branch from what I've learned here (definitely not necessary but couldn't hurt). Have a great day!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you get stuck coming up with the `IF`s and I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Would going about this scenario using IF AND OR branches be an effective way to go about this or a route more like multiple branches of IFs? I am attempting IF AND OR but am getting errors stating that there are "too many arguments", an example being =IF(Status="grad",(AND(sem_1="present",sem_2="present")),5,0)+IF(status="ugrad",(OR,(sem_1="present",sem_2="present")),5,0)

Comment: The problem with IFs in this case is that the formula gets unnecessarily complicated... Ideally you'll use all of the ANDs and OR in a single IF statement. Reading out loud: "IF ((graduate AND present AND present) OR (undergraduate AND (present OR present))) then 5 else 0"

Comment: @AnteGrizelj Did you ever figure out how to write the IF statements?